# How do I use a Dynamic table name?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, dynamic

I have a database where every Company has it's own table and the same table names in all companies, like:

```
[COMPANY 1$Cities], [COMPANY 1$Customers], [COMPANY 1$Documents]  
[COMPANY 2$Cities], [COMPANY 2$Customers], [COMPANY 2$Documents]   
[COMPANY 3$Cities], [COMPANY 3$Customers], [COMPANY 3$Documents]
```

I have a Stored Procedure that works fine when I select a value from a specific Company.

But, the problem is that I have to create this Stored Procedure for **EVERY** Company that we have in our Database, and that's a lot (and I think it's not the best decision, based on database performance)

Finally, I'd like to know if there is a way to select the values from a specific company, using parameters IN the **TABLE NAME**.

Something like `SELECT +@CityName+ FROM [dbo].[@CompanyName+$Cities]`

Comment: you could just create separate schemas for separate company tables. But if you shared the script of your stored procedure and sample data to simulate that can explain your question better

Comment: Fix your data model!  That is the place to start.

Comment: And if you can't fix it there is always dynamic SQL, which is a complex subject I suggest you google and do some reading on.

Comment: I can't change anything on the data model, it is standard from a ERP that we use :(

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to compose dynamic SQL for this task. Create a [database `VIEW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) where you union all your companies' tables and add constant company code. Then you can filter your data on that company code and get what you need with general SQL.

But anyway such database design is very strange and hard to manage. You can use partitioned table and apply data security to restrict the data on company.

Answer (score 0):

@Kelson, I am not sure in what context you are running this. If you can store a table name in a variable if you are in SQLCMD context.

To change the context to SQLCMD go to SSMS menu and click on Query -> SQLCMD Mode

Here is an image for it:
[image]

After you changed that you are able to run something like this:

```
:setvar TableCompanyCity1 "TableName1"
:setvar TableCompanyCity2 "TableName2"

select * from dbo.$(TableCompanyCity1)
select * from dbo.$(TableCompanyCity2)
```